# Recommended antivirus applications for Linux

Tags: security

As a semi-new Linux user concerned about computer security. I have read Internet articles on Linux anti-virus (AV) applications. Most posts are outdated. There is a dearth of anyone reviewing Linux AV apps.

Does anyone have any recommendations on good AV for Linux, or even more specific, for elementary? I'm concerned with how secure and robust the apps are, as well as how it is with system resources.

(*Please note that this question is *not* intended for folks to opine on why AV isn't needed on Linux, etc.*)

Comment: Sophos anti virus is what I use.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a system integrated solution I would suggest the Open Source Antivirus [ClamAV](https://www.clamav.net/).

`sudo apt install clamav`

or its GTK graphical user interface [ClamTK](https://github.com/dave-theunsub/clamtk/)

`sudo apt install clamtk`

It is intended to be an easy to use, light-weight, on-demand scanner
for Linux systems. It has been ported to Fedora, Debian, RedHat,
openSUSE, ALT Linux, Ubuntu, CentOS, Gentoo, Archlinux, Mandriva,
PCLinuxOS, Frugalware, FreeBSD, and others.

Comment: I had read about ClamAV; it seems to be the most popular AV out there. Perhaps it's because so many other vendors seem to have dropped Linux support (why, is beyond me). Looking at the GitHub site, it looked like it hadn't been updated recently. Clam TK looks like there is some activity, so maybe that's a good option. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sophos does a good job detecting both windows and linux malware https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-antivirus-for-linux.aspx

Comment: Sophos is relatively easy to set up, has auto updating, and on-access file scanning.

Answer (score 0):

Avast in my opinion, for either Windows or Linux although I generally only use the Linux version to scan windows partitons. I use selinux to secure Linux machines. It's not an antivirus but it stops programs writing to locations and areas of memory that it shouldn't need to. I've never needed an antivirus on Linux as programs need root access to install and you'd have to be pretty dumb to enter your root password just cos it randomly asked for it.

Comment: Since I have been using Avast on Windows PCs for years, that was actually my first option. Unfortunately, they don't advertise on their website any Linux version, other than a server edition, and that doesn't even look like it's up-to-date. I'll look at selinux for my other security needs; thanks.